# Calculating a value in continuous form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I currently am using a continuous form in MS Access that the users input values into one field. In the form there are three records under one field. I'm not sure if this is possible or even how to do it, but I would like to subtract the value in the first record from the value in the second to calculate the value for the 3rd. [Form in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkPYR.png)

In the example I provided it would be 20-10 and then have the third record be 10. The field name is Initial_Value. I've been looking online and I haven't seen any information on how to grab those values to do this with VBA. The name of the form is "frm_main_process_values" and is a subform of "frm_main_msmt".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add column with measurement type (initial, final, change, it can be hidden) and use for Value textbox with calculated control source based on function: `=CalcDrop([ResType],[Result])`.
And create public function in module with static variables, which remember previous values:

```
Public Function CalcDrop(strResType As String, lngVal As Long) As Long
Static lngInit As Long
Static lngFinal As Long

Select Case strResType
    Case "initial"
        lngInit = lngVal
        CalcDrop = lngVal
    Case "final"
        lngFinal = lngVal
        CalcDrop = lngVal
    Case "change"
        CalcDrop = lngInit - lngFinal
End Select
End Function
```

You will need to make sure that the rows order is the same for each series: initial, final, change. Here are results, column "Value" is calculated:
[image: Here are results, column "Value" is calculated]

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in a continuous form, since the `Value` textbox has only one ControlSource, it can't be a bound field and a calculated value at the same time.

If it's **always** three records, and you pre-fill the form with the three records, and they have a defined order with a sorting field, you could have a button that calculates the value and writes it to the third record. But that would be a very odd usage of a continuous form.